# How to pass variable object as a value argument

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have a self defined datatype, and a global variable of said type. I pass this global variable as an argument to several methods, the value of the variable seems to change unintentionally.

I discovered that all objects are passed as reference parameters even when not declared as var parameters (or so I think).

So I tried to fix the problem by introducing a local variable to all the methods that I pass the object into, then assigning the local variable to the parameter, and then declaring the object parameter as a const - yet the value of the global variable still changes, how do I overcome this?

```
{unit something}
interface

   uses
      SysUtils

   type
      ByteArr = Array of Byte;
      Num = record
         sign : byte;
         int : ByteArr;
         frac : ByteArr;
      end;

   function StrToNum(input : string):Num;
   function NumToStr(input : Num):string;
   function Dostuff(const a : Num):Num

implementation

    function StrToNum(input : string):Num;
    begin
       //code to convert a string into 'Num' type
    end;

    function NumToStr(input : Num):string;
    begin
       //code to output a string version of a 'Num' input
    end;

    function Dostuff(const a : Num):Num
    var
       somevar : num;
    begin
       somevar := a;
       code; //code to change value of 'somevar'
       result := somevar;
    end;       

end.

{console program}
uses
   something in 'something.pas';
var
   globalvar : num;

begin
   globalvar := StrToNum('2');
   writeln(NumToStr(globalvar)); //shows 2
   writeln(NumToStr(Dostuff(globalvar))); //shows correct value
   writeln(numtostr(globalvar)); //no longer displays 2
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dynamic array is a reference type. Your type `ByteArr` is a dynamic array, and therefore a reference type. Assignment of variables of such a type is reference assignment rather than value assignment.

Consider this code:

```
var
  A, B: ByteArr;
....
SetLength(A, 1);
A[0] := 0;
B := A;
Writeln(A[0]);
B[0] := 42;
Writeln(A[0]);
```

This will output

```
0
42
```

That's because after `B := A` the two variables **refer** to the same array.

Use `Copy` to make a new array that is a copy of the first:

```
B := Copy(A);
```

Comment: Is there a more general method that i can use to copy the value of any datatype?

Comment: You cannot write a deep copy function that can work for arbitrary data types. But you could use enhanced RTTI to make a deep copy for a certainly class of types.

Answer (score 0):

Object is a pointer type. Some pointers (object copies) could address the same memory piece, so modification of one copy influences other ones.
You problem is not well defined, but I suspect you might need "deep copy" of object contents - for example with help of `Assign` - inherit class from `TPersistent` and implement `AssignTo` method.